# Bootstrap 3: Offset isn't working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, offset

I have this code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-12 col-md-offset-0"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-12"></div>
</div>
```

What I want for small (sm) screens is to have two divs that have three columns each, and an offset of 6 columns for the first div.

For medium (md) screens, I would like to have two divs with twelve columns each (one horizontally stacked under the other), with no offsets.

Somehow the browser doesn't recognize the class `col-md-offset-0`. It still uses the `col-sm-offset-6` class. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're looking for since your code currently only has 2 columns. Can you create a [Bootply](http://bootply.com)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Which version of bootstrap are you using?  The early versions of Bootstrap 3 (3.0, 3.0.1) didn't work with this functionality.

col-md-offset-0 should be working as seen in this bootstrap example found here (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6">.col-sm-5 .col-md-6</div>
   <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0">.col-sm-5 .col-sm-offset-2 .col-md-6 .col-md-offset-0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yep, that's it, early version of Bootstrap3 is the answer

Comment: You can always use offset0 for other xs-ls-md :: col-lg-9  col-lg-offset-0 col-md-offset-1 col-md-8

Answer (score 0):

There is no col-??-offset-0.  All "rows" assume there is no offset unless it has been specified.  I think you are wanting 3 rows on a small screen and 1 row on a medium screen.

To get the result I believe you are looking for try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
        <p>On small screen there are 3 rows, and on a medium screen 1 row</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
        <p>On small screen there are 3 rows, and on a medium screen 1 row</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
        <p>On small screen there are 3 rows, and on a medium screen 1 row</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Keep in mind you will only see a difference on a small tablet with what you described.  Medium, large, and extra small screens the columns are spanning 12.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want something that seems to be the opposite of what is desired normally: you want a horizontal layout for small screens and vertically stacked elements on large screens. You may achieve this in a way like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">a</div>
        <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-3">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">c</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

On small screens, i.e. xs and sm, this generates one row with two columns with an offset of 6. On larger screens, i.e. md and lg, it generates two vertically stacked elements in full width (12 columns).